# UnsameQ exhibits different behavior than !SameQ

Tags: functions

I do not understand the `UnsameQ[]` behavior below. (I need `UnsameQ[]` as I may have variables in the array.)

```
{-7, 3, 2} /. x_ /; x == 3 -> w
(*{-7, w, 2}*)

{-7, 3, 2} /. x_ /; x != 3 -> w
(*{w, 3, w}*)

{-7, 3, 2} /. x_ /; x === 3 -> w
(*{-7, w, 2}*)

{-7, 3, 2} /. x_ /; x =!= 3 -> w
(*w*)
```

Comment: `{a} /. _ -> "who said it works only at the first level?"` and `{} != 3` vs `{} =!= 3`.

Comment: @Kuba, thank you for your reply. However, I do not fully understand. Apparently in the `UnsameQ[]` case, the entire `{-7,3,2}` is becoming `x` (/after/ the first level?) and not the same as 3. Why does that not continue with `Unequal[]`? (For that matter, I am a tad stymied why `{}!=3` does not return False.)

Comment: `! SameQ[]` would be `{-7, 3, 2} /. x_ /; ! (x === 3) -> w`, which returns the same as `UnsameQ[]`.  But `! Equal[]` is different than `UnsameQ[]`, as your 2nd and 4th examples show.

Comment: Perhaps you want `Replace[list,  x_ /; x =!= 3 -> w, 1]` or `Replace[list,  x_ /; x =!= 3 -> w, Infinity]`

Comment: @Michael E2, thank you for your reply. Yes, I also played with `!SameQ[]`. I see that `!Equal[]` and `UnsameQ[]` are different, my questions are: why? and why should I have known that? Also, I would appreciate a pointer to some documentation, explaining why `{}!=3` does not return `False`. Thank you.

Comment: Much of this is discussed under the "Background and Context" section of the doc pages for `SameQ`, `UnsameQ`, `Equal` and `Unequal`. For instance, "Unequal[Subscript[expr, 1],Subscript[expr, 2]] returns True if Subscript[expr, 1] and Subscript[expr, 2] are numerically unequal, False if they are equal and unevaluated if equality cannot be established."  I suppose `{}` and `3` are not numerically unequal, since `{}` is not numerical.

Answer (score 6):

`w != 3` returns unevaluated, thus no replacement will ever happen since it will never match.

`/.` is ReplaceAll, it happens at all levels. At level 0, `{-7, 3, 2} =!= 3` is true, so the replacement is made and there are no more levels left to traverse.

Edit:

I suggest using replace with a level spec:

`Replace[{-7, 3, 2}, x_ /; x =!= 3 -> w, {1}]`

Comment: Thank you. I'm okay with the `Replace[]` levels. Still trying to wrap my head around why `{-7,3,2}!=3` is not `True`.

Answer (score 3):

As a diagnostic tool for these sorts of things, if you sneak in a `Print[]` statement you can see what is going on in all of your cases. For the `=!=` versus the `!=` you can see the `UnsameQ` always evaluates to true or false while the `!=` doesn't.

```
{-7, 3, 2} /. x_ /; (Print["x= ", x, " : ", x =!= 3]; x =!= 3) -> w
```

> x= {-7,3,2} : True

Now the `!=`

```
{-7, 3, 2} /. x_ /; (Print["x= ", x, " : ", x != 3]; x != 3) -> w
```

> x= {-7,3,2} : {-7,3,2}!=3
>
> x= List : List!=3
>
> x= -7 : True
>
> x= 3 : False
>
> x= 2 : True

Comment: Thank you, I like this diagnostic use of `Print[]`. :-)  What remains for me to understand is why `{-7,3,2}!=3` does not simplify to `True`. I guess it is like @Michael E2 mentioned, that the two are not /numerically/ unequal, since a `List[]` is not numerical. If there is a better explanation, I am all ears, thanx.

Comment: Hi All. I still would like to understand why `{1,2,3}==9` returns unevaluated. @Michael E2 had written something about the `List[]` not being `NumericQ[]`. (I can no longer find that comment.) But in that case: `"asdf"==9` should also return unevaluated, since `"asdf"` is not `NumericQ[]` -- but it returns `False`. Any pointers would be most appreciated here. Thank you. (Should I open a new question?)